# How to get data using the until activity

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I would like to use the until activity and take data for a specified date.
Can you please tell me how to do this?

The data is stored in GEN2 as AAA/year/mm/day by day.

[image: pipeline image]

Comment: can you share what you have tried and error you are facing?

Comment: what is the until condition? or you want data till that particular date or for any specific date?

Comment: I don't know the formula for until activity.
I want to get all yyyy/mm/dd/xxx.parquet data from a specific date to a specific date.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to get all yyyy/mm/dd/xxx.parquet data from a specific date to a specific date.

I could able to achieve your requirement by **incrementing dates inside until activity**.

This is my folder structure and sample csv files.

```
data
    2023
        02
            26
                csv26.csv
            27
                csv27.csv
            28
                csv28.csv
        03
            01
                csv01.csv
            02
                csv02.csv
```

Here my date range is from `26-02-2023` to `02-03-2023`. For `counter variable` I have given it as `startdate-1` `(2023/02/25)`.

[image]

**Until condition:** `@equals(string(pipeline().parameters.end_date),variables('counter'))`

Inside until, we have to increment the day by 1. As self-referencing the variables is not supported in ADF, I have taken a `temp` string variable and stored the incremented date in it with below expression.

`@formatdatetime(adddays(formatdatetime(variables('counter'),'yyyy/MM/dd'),1),'yyyy/MM/dd')`

After this, I have reassigned the `temp` variable to `counter` variable.

Now, take a copy activity and for source use the wild card path and give the `counter` variable like below. I have used `csv` files, for you give it as `*.parquet`.

[image]

**This is my Pipeline JSON:**

```
{
"name": "pipeline2",
"properties": {
    "activities": [
        {
            "name": "Until1",
            "type": "Until",
            "dependsOn": [
                {
                    "activity": "Set variable3",
                    "dependencyConditions": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "userProperties": [],
            "typeProperties": {
                "expression": {
                    "value": "@equals(string(pipeline().parameters.end_date),variables('counter'))",
                    "type": "Expression"
                },
                "activities": [
                    {
                        "name": "Temp",
                        "type": "SetVariable",
                        "dependsOn": [],
                        "userProperties": [],
                        "typeProperties": {
                            "variableName": "temp",
                            "value": {
                                "value": "@formatdatetime(adddays(formatdatetime(variables('counter'),'yyyy/MM/dd'),1),'yyyy/MM/dd')",
                                "type": "Expression"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Incrementing Counter",
                        "type": "SetVariable",
                        "dependsOn": [
                            {
                                "activity": "Temp",
                                "dependencyConditions": [
                                    "Succeeded"
                                ]
                            }
                        ],
                        "userProperties": [],
                        "typeProperties": {
                            "variableName": "counter",
                            "value": {
                                "value": "@variables('temp')",
                                "type": "Expression"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Copy data1",
                        "type": "Copy",
                        "dependsOn": [
                            {
                                "activity": "Incrementing Counter",
                                "dependencyConditions": [
                                    "Succeeded"
                                ]
                            }
                        ],
                        "policy": {
                            "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                            "retry": 0,
                            "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                            "secureOutput": false,
                            "secureInput": false
                        },
                        "userProperties": [],
                        "typeProperties": {
                            "source": {
                                "type": "DelimitedTextSource",
                                "storeSettings": {
                                    "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
                                    "recursive": true,
                                    "wildcardFolderPath": {
                                        "value": "@variables('counter')",
                                        "type": "Expression"
                                    },
                                    "wildcardFileName": "*.csv",
                                    "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                                },
                                "formatSettings": {
                                    "type": "DelimitedTextReadSettings"
                                }
                            },
                            "sink": {
                                "type": "DelimitedTextSink",
                                "storeSettings": {
                                    "type": "AzureBlobFSWriteSettings"
                                },
                                "formatSettings": {
                                    "type": "DelimitedTextWriteSettings",
                                    "quoteAllText": true,
                                    "fileExtension": ".txt"
                                }
                            },
                            "enableStaging": false,
                            "translator": {
                                "type": "TabularTranslator",
                                "typeConversion": true,
                                "typeConversionSettings": {
                                    "allowDataTruncation": true,
                                    "treatBooleanAsNumber": false
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "inputs": [
                            {
                                "referenceName": "Sourcefiles",
                                "type": "DatasetReference"
                            }
                        ],
                        "outputs": [
                            {
                                "referenceName": "target",
                                "type": "DatasetReference"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "timeout": "0.12:00:00"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Set variable3",
            "type": "SetVariable",
            "dependsOn": [],
            "userProperties": [],
            "typeProperties": {
                "variableName": "counter",
                "value": {
                    "value": "@pipeline().parameters.st_date",
                    "type": "Expression"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "parameters": {
        "st_date": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "2023/02/25"
        },
        "end_date": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "2023/03/02"
        }
    },
    "variables": {
        "counter": {
            "type": "String"
        },
        "temp": {
            "type": "String"
        }
    },
    "annotations": []
}
}
```

Execute this and you can see the files are copied to the target.

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Thank you for your reply.
I actually did it and was able to do it! Thank you very much.